# Event loops and signal-slot processing when using multithreading in Qt

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, event-loop, signals-slots

I've been having some problems with using `QThreads` which made me explore different combinations before I've found the right one. However I still don't fully understand what is really happening in the four cases shown below when it comes to event loops and signal-slot processing.

I added some comments to OUTPUT section, but as you can see I'm not sure if my assumptions about what caused observed behaviors are correct. Also I'm not sure if `case 3` is something that might be used in real code. Here is my test code (only the `main.cpp` differs for each case):

> worker.h:

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>

class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Worker(QObject *parent = 0) { this->isRunning_ = false;}
    bool isRunning() const { return isRunning_; }

signals:
    void processingFinished();
    void inProgress();

public slots:
    void process()
    {
        this->isRunning_ = true;
        qDebug() << this << "processing started";
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            QThread::usleep(1000);
            emit this->inProgress();
        }
        qDebug() << this << "processing finished";
        this->isRunning_ = false;
        emit this->processingFinished();
    }

private:
    bool isRunning_;
};
```

> workermanager.h:

```
#include "worker.h"

class WorkerManager : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit WorkerManager(QObject *parent = 0) :
        QObject(parent) {}

public slots:
    void process()
    {
        QThread *thread = new QThread();
        Worker  *worker = new Worker();

        connect(thread,SIGNAL(started()),worker,SLOT(process()));
        connect(worker,SIGNAL(processingFinished()),this,SLOT(slot1()));
        connect(worker,SIGNAL(inProgress()),this,SLOT(slot2()));
        worker->moveToThread(thread);

        qDebug() << "starting";
        thread->start();
        QThread::usleep(500);
        while(worker->isRunning()) { }
        qDebug() << "finished";
    }

    void slot1() { qDebug() << "slot1"; }
    void slot2() { qDebug() << "slot2"; }
};
```

> main.cpp (case 1 - no separate thread for `workerManager`):

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "workermanager.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    WorkerManager* workerManager = new WorkerManager;    
    workerManager->process();
    qDebug() << "end";
    return a.exec();
}
```

> OUTPUT - both `slot1` and `slot2` called at `a.exec()` (??? - using main event loop?):

```
starting 
Worker(0x112db20) processing started 
Worker(0x112db20) processing finished 
finished 
end
slot2 
slot2 
slot2 
slot2 
slot2 
slot1
```

> main.cpp (case 2 - `workerManager` moved to separate thread, but thread not started):

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "workermanager.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    WorkerManager* workerManager = new WorkerManager;
    QThread *thread = new QThread();   
    workerManager->moveToThread(thread);       
    workerManager->process();
    qDebug() << "end";
    return a.exec();
}
```

> OUTPUT - neither `slot1` nor `slot2` was called - (??? event loop associated with thread receives signals but since thread was not started slots are not called?):

```
starting 
Worker(0x112db20) processing started 
Worker(0x112db20) processing finished 
finished 
end
```

> main.cpp (case 3 - `workerManager` moved to separate thread, thread started but `workerManager::process()` called via `workerManager->process()`):

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "workermanager.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    WorkerManager* workerManager = new WorkerManager;
    QThread *thread = new QThread();   
    workerManager->moveToThread(thread); 
    thread->start();     
    workerManager->process();
    qDebug() << "end";
    return a.exec();
}
```

> OUTPUT - `slot2` called while `Worker` still executing its `process()` (???):

```
starting 
Worker(0x197bb20) processing started 
slot2 
slot2 
slot2 
slot2 
Worker(0x197bb20) processing finished 
finished 
end 
slot2 
slot1
```

> main.cpp (case 4 - `workerManager` moved to separate thread, thread started but `workerManager::process()` called using `started()` signal from `thread`):

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "workermanager.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    WorkerManager* workerManager = new WorkerManager;
    QThread *thread = new QThread();    
    workerManager->moveToThread(thread);
    QObject::connect(thread,SIGNAL(started()),workerManager,SLOT(process()));
    thread->start();
    qDebug() << "end";
    return a.exec();
}
```

> OUTPUT - all events processed after reaching `a.exec()` (???):

```
end 
starting 
Worker(0x7f1d700013d0) processing started 
Worker(0x7f1d700013d0) processing finished 
finished 
slot2 
slot2 
slot2 
slot2 
slot2 
slot1
```

Thanks for any clarifications.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

All results you got are perfectly correct. I'll try to explain how this works.

An event loop is an internal loop in Qt code that processes system and user events. Event loop of main thread is started when you call `a.exec()`. Event loop of another thread is started by default implementation of `QThread::run`.

When Qt decides it's time to process an event, it executes its event handler. While event handler is working, Qt has no chance to process any other event (unless given directly by `QApplication::processEvents()` or some other methods). Once the event handler is finished, control flow returns to the event loop and Qt may execute another handler to process another event.

Signals and slots are not the same as events and event handlers in Qt terminology. But slots are handled by event loops somewhat similarily. If you have control flow in your code(such as in `main` function) you can execute any slot immediately just as any other C++ function. But when Qt does that it can only do that from an event loop. It should be noted that signals are always sent immediately, while slot execution may be delayed.

Now let's see what happens in each case.

#### Case 1

`WorkerManager::process` is executed directly at the program start. New thread is started and `Worker::process` is executed immediately in the new thread. `WorkerManager::process` continues execution until Worker is done, freezing all other actions (including slot processing) in main thread. After `WorkerManager::process` is finished, control flow goes to `QApplication::exec`. Qt establishes connection to the other thread, receives messages about slot invokation and invokes all of them consequently.

#### Case 2

Qt by default executes slots of an object in the thread this object belongs to. Main thread will not execute slots of `WorkerManager` because it belongs to another thread. However this thread is never started. Its event loop is never finished. Invokations of `slot1` and `slot2` are left forever in Qt's queue waiting for you to start the thread. Sad story.

#### Case 3

In this case `WorkerManager::process` is executed in main thread because you invoke it directly from main thread. Meanwhile, `WorkerManager`'s thread is started. Its event loop is launched and waiting for events. `WorkerManager::process` starts `Worker`'s thread and executes `Worker::exec` in it. `Worker` starts sending signals to `WorkerManager`. `WorkerManager`'s thread almost immediately starts to execute appropriate slots. At this point it seems awkward that `WorkerManager::slot2` and `WorkerManager::process` are executed simultaneously. But it's perfectly fine, at least if `WorkerManager` is thread-safe. Shortly after `Worker` is done, `WorkerManager::process` is finished and `a.exec()` is executed but has not much to process.

#### Case 4

Main function just launches `WorkerManager`'s thread and immediately goes to `a.exec()`, resulting in `end` as first line in the output. `a.exec()` processes something and ensures program execution but doesn't execute `WorkerManager`'s slots because it belongs to another thread.  `WorkerManager::process` is executed in `WorkerManager`'s thread from its event loop. `Worker`'s thread is started and `Worker::process` starts sending signals from `Worker`'s thread to `WorkerManager`'s thread. Unfortunately the latter is busy executing `WorkerManager::process`. When `Worker` is done, `WorkerManager::process` also finishes and `WorkerManager`'s thread immediately executes all queued slots.

The largest problem in your code is `usleep` and infinite loops. You should almost never use those when working with Qt. I understand that a sleep in `Worker::process` is just a placeholder for some real calculation. But you should remove sleep and infinite loop from `WorkerManager`. Use `WorkerManager::slot1` to detect `Worker`'s termination. If you develop a GUI application there would be no need to move `WorkerManager` to another thread. All its methods (without sleep) will be executed fast and will not freeze the GUI.